# How to combine rows based upon matching column variable

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a huge query but I have an sub-example for understanding. I apologize in advance, my first time asking a question with my amateur skills.

I have two rows from an output. There are many columns, but only three have data on a single row at a time (always the case), the rest being null. How do I combine these two rows because both share a common variable in two of the columns (i.e. IDs and Pass_numb the same tells me I want them combined)?

Essentially, how does both rows combine into and fill in the null values? Keep in mind that this simple result/example is already the output from other queries.

This simple visual is the result from sub-queries

```
Pass_numb   ID_1      Restriction_1     Pass_numb_2  ID_2     Restriction_2
-----       -----     --------------    -----        ----     --------------
NULL        NULL      NULL              1            1000     ENL
1           10000     LS                NULL         NULL     NULL
```

I am more so asking for conceptual help as I have no idea how to help explain exactly what I am after without typing a book. Any general suggestions or pointing to specific topic-resources would be great.

I would expect to see the following from my simple example above:

```
Pass_numb   ID_1      Restriction_1     Pass_numb_2  ID_2     Restriction_2
-----       -----     --------------    -----        ----     --------------
1           10000     LS                1            1000     ENL
```

Thanks so much if anyone can lend a hand or lead me somewhere!

Comment: Are these two rows from the same table or from two different tables. What do your table(s) look like and what is your query? My suspicion is combining two rows from the same table, but I can't tell how pass_numb and id are related.

Comment: Essentially, pass_numb, ID_1, and Restriction_1 is from one table. The following three columns from a separate table. So this shows the two tables joined together. Each table has a different kind of 'restriction' and that is why I will always see NULLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, you could use aggregation:

```
select max(Pass_numb) as Pass_numb,
       max(ID_1) as ID_1,
       max(Restriction_1) as Restriction_1,
       max(Pass_numb_2) as Pass_numb_2,
       max(ID_2) as ID_2
from t
group by coalesce(Pass_numb, Pass_numb_2);
```

That said, there is probably a way to fix the subquery so it does not do this.  However, if it is complicated, that  might require rewriting a lot of code.

Comment: Gordon, I am sure you are correct that my issue resides somewhere in my subs. But alas, that will be another day. However, your suggestion has worked like a charm in my testing. Here's to hoping it holds through in the entire query. Thank you very much for your time.